# PHP interpolating string for function output

Tags: php, string, string-interpolation

PHP supports [variable interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation) in double quoted strings, for example,

```
$s = "foo $bar";
```

But is it possible to interpolate function call results in the double quoted string?

For example,

```
$s = "foo {bar()}";
```

Something like that? It doesn't seem not possible, right?

Comment: yes it is not possible. You can get your answer simply by trying

Comment: Did you mean *interpolating* or *interpreting*?

Comment: Interpolating is the correct word here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The double quote feature in PHP does not evaluate PHP code, it simply replaces variables with their values. If you want to actually evaluate PHP code dynamically (very dangerous), you should use `eval`:

```
eval( "function foo() { bar() }" );
```

Or if you just want to create a function:

```
$foo = create_function( "", "bar()" );
$foo();
```

Only use this if there really is no other option.

Comment: If the function was inside a class, then you can refer it inside string, for e.g.: `$s = "foo {$this->bar()}";`

Comment: @nawfal and the `{}` are required. Otherwise php will look for `bar` property.

Answer (score 29):

It is absolutely possible using the string-to-function-name calling technique as [Overv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10758537/php-interpolating-string-for-function-output/10758569#10758569) indicates. In many trivial substitution cases it reads far better than the alternative syntaxes such as

```
"<input value='<?php echo 1 + 1 + foo() / bar(); ?>' />"
```

You need a variable, because the parser expects the $ to be there.

This is where the identity transform works well as a syntactic hack. Just declare an identity function, and assign the name to a variable in scope:

```
function identity($arg){return $arg;}
$interpolate = "identity";
```

Then you can pass any valid PHP expression as the function argument:

```
"<input value='{$interpolate(1 + 1 + foo() / bar() )}' />"
```

The upside is that you can eliminate a *lot* of trivial local variables and [echo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) statements.

The downside is that the $interpolate variable falls out of scope, so you would have to repeatedly declare it global inside of functions and methods.

Comment: Also, let's hope this goes through: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/arbitrary_expression_interpolation

Answer (score 0):

Unless interpolation is absolutely necessary (please comment and let me know why), concatenate the function output with the string.

```
$s =  "foo " . bar();
```

Source: *[1.8. Interpolating Functions and Expressions Within Strings](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/pcook/ch01_08.htm)*

Comment: Ok but actually this does not answer the question ;-)

Comment: Not, but it does give the correct solution to the underlying problem, which is to construct a string consisting of both literals parts and expressions.